# Can someone explain this console output?

Tags: javascript, debugging

When I run following in the `console`

```
console.log("1");
setTimeout(function(){console.log("2");},3000);
console.log("3");
setTimeout(function(){console.log("4");},1000);
```

I get this:

[image]

What is the number written in blue color after `3` & before `4`?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: share your full code of this function, plz

Comment: @MrNeo That is all the code....

Comment: I checked it on jsfiddle, but it's not have the number as the question @@

Comment: @MrNeo COpy the code , paste into the code, not a fiddle...

Comment: @MrNeo Try it in Google Chrome console.

Comment: I had tried on both jsfiddle and code snippet of SO, but not get this number, I only get: `1, 3, 4, 2` ^^. Hope to get the correct answer :D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

that number is the return value of the last statement you executed.

```
console.log("1");
setTimeout(function(){console.log("2");},3000);
console.log("3");
setTimeout(function(){console.log("4");},1000);//-- the return of this call
```

the first line prints the `1`, the return value is `undefined` but is discarded
the second line creates the 3 seconds timer, the return value is the timer reference but again is discarded
the third line prints the `3`, the return value is `undefined` but is discarded
the last line creates the 1 second timer, since this is the last statement the result of the statement is printed
1 second later the `4` prints
then finally the `2` prints

Answer (score 5):

That number is the ID of the last timeout which is returned after calling the the `setTimeout` function. The ID can be used for clearing the timeout using `clearTimeout` function. `clearTimeout(timeoutId)`

Answer (score -2):

It may be code that you didn't include in this post executing from a different place, when checked on JS Bin this code obviously shows only 1,2,3,4

https://jsbin.com/ciqelelani/edit?js,console,output